# Convert id-keyed objects into array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

I have the following object with nested object which are identified by their own ID as its key. I don't feel this is a proper way to work with Angular and so I need to get rid of the ID keys as each object has already their own id as its property.

```
{
  "1": {
    "id": 1,
    "questionGroup": "Mathematics",
    "questions": {
      "1": {
        "id": 1,
        "questionTitle": "2+2",
        "questionType": "singleChoice",
        "answerOptions": {
          "1": {
            "id": 1,
            "answerOptionText": "4"
          },
          "2": {
            "id": 2,
            "answerOptionText": "3"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "2": {
    "id": 2,
    "questionGroup": "Geography",
    "questions": {
      "3": {
        "id": 3
      }
    }
  },
  "3": {
    "id": 3,
    "questionGroup": "Philosophy",
    "questions": {
      "4": {
        "id": 4
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But I need to convert it into the following one:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "questionGroup": "Mathematics",
    "questions": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "questionTitle": "2+2",
        "questionType": "singleChoice",
        "answerOptions": [
          {
            "id": 1,
            "answerOptionText": "4"
          },
          {
            "id": 2,
            "answerOptionText": "3"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "questionGroup": "Geography",
    "questions": [
      {
        "id": 3
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "questionGroup": "Philosophy",
    "questions": [
      {
        "id": 4
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I would like to see answers using the most JavaScript modern way to deal with this, as I don't feel pretty to use my old-fashion way with many nested iterators and conditions.

```
json_result = [];
db.query(`SELECT ex.id, ex.name, qgrp.id as questionGroupId, qgrp.name as questionGroupName, ans.id as answerOptionId, ans.\`text\` as questionName, ans.question_type as questionType, ansopt.id as answerOptionId, ansopt.display_text as answerOptionText FROM _questionGroup qgrp
    INNER JOIN exam ex 
    ON ex.id = qgrp.examId 
    INNER JOIN question ans 
    ON ans.questionGroupId = qgrp.id 
    INNER JOIN answerOption ansopt 
    ON ansopt.answerOptionId  = ans.id
    AND ex.id = ?;`, [req.params.id], (err, rows, results) => {
        if(!err) {
            var index = {}, questionGroup = {}, question = {};

            rows.forEach(function (row) {
                console.log("ROW: ", row);
                if ( !(row.id in index) ) {
                    index[row.id] = {
                        id: row.id,
                        name: row.name,
                        questionGroup: {}
                    };
                    json_result.push(index[row.id]);
                }
                if( !(row.questionGroupId in questionGroup) ) {
                    questionGroup[row.questionGroupId] = {
                        id: row.questionGroupId,
                        name: row.questionGroupName,
                        question: {}
                    };
                    index[row.id].questionGroup[row.questionGroupId] = questionGroup[row.questionGroupId];
                }
                if( !(row.answerOptionId in question) ) {
                    question[row.answerOptionId] = {
                        id: row.answerOptionId,
                        name: row.questionName,
                        question_type: row.questionType,
                        answerOptions: []
                    }
                }
                question[row.answerOptionId].answerOptions.push({
                    id: row.answerOptionId,
                    name: row.answerOptionText,
                });

                index[row.id].questionGroup[row.questionGroupId].question[row.answerOptionId] = question[row.answerOptionId];
            });


            res.status(200).json(json_result);
        } else {
            res.status(410).json(err);
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: `Object.values(data)`

Comment: This isn't a code-writing service. Include what you've tried.

Comment: Sorry! I'll add more context

Comment: Thank you @Keith. This amazingly solved the problem. I'll post as Question answer to others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment from @Keith helped to find the solution, which is about to add `Object.values(json_result)` ([Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values)) to the response data. As following:

```
json_result = [];
db.query(`SELECT ex.id, ex.name, qgrp.id as questionGroupId, qgrp.name as questionGroupName, ans.id as answerOptionId, ans.\`text\` as questionName, ans.question_type as questionType, ansopt.id as answerOptionId, ansopt.display_text as answerOptionText FROM _questionGroup qgrp
    INNER JOIN exam ex 
    ON ex.id = qgrp.examId 
    INNER JOIN question ans 
    ON ans.questionGroupId = qgrp.id 
    INNER JOIN answerOption ansopt 
    ON ansopt.answerOptionId  = ans.id
    AND ex.id = ?;`, [req.params.id], (err, rows, results) => {
        if(!err) {
            var index = {}, questionGroup = {}, question = {};

            rows.forEach(function (row) {
                console.log("ROW: ", row);
                if ( !(row.id in index) ) {
                    index[row.id] = {
                        id: row.id,
                        name: row.name,
                        questionGroup: {}
                    };
                    json_result.push(index[row.id]);
                }
                if( !(row.questionGroupId in questionGroup) ) {
                    questionGroup[row.questionGroupId] = {
                        id: row.questionGroupId,
                        name: row.questionGroupName,
                        question: {}
                    };
                    index[row.id].questionGroup[row.questionGroupId] = questionGroup[row.questionGroupId];
                }
                if( !(row.answerOptionId in question) ) {
                    question[row.answerOptionId] = {
                        id: row.answerOptionId,
                        name: row.questionName,
                        question_type: row.questionType,
                        answerOptions: []
                    }
                }
                question[row.answerOptionId].answerOptions.push({
                    id: row.answerOptionId,
                    name: row.answerOptionText,
                });

                index[row.id].questionGroup[row.questionGroupId].question[row.answerOptionId] = question[row.answerOptionId];
            });


            res.status(200).json(Object.values(json_result));
        } else {
            res.status(410).json(err);
        }
    }
);
```